# How do I undelete an app without losing data?

Tags: iphone

My little sister accidentally deleted one of my iPhone games. I know I can get it back by "rebuying" or resynching it via iTunes, but this will give me a clean install, without all my saved game state. Is there any way for me to reverse the deletion without losing all this information?

Answer (score 4):

You can restore from your last backup that contained the game, however you will lose any new additions you've made on the phone since the backup. iTunes normally makes a backup every few syncs or days, depending on how often you have plugged it in.

I would first try and just re-install the game since she may have removed the game but not the actual data associated to it.

Apart from that there is no way to recover the data, since the iPhone does an immediate delete of all files once instructed to do so.

Comment: When you say iTunes normally makes a backup every few days, will it do this even if I haven't plugged my phone into a computer? I have the same problem with a game of mine but haven't had my phone plugged into a computer for months! Thanks

Comment: @Lorrainedodge That should be another question - however it will backup if you have chosen to backup to iClould or you have used WiFi in the same network as your computer